# How do I set IsTabStop for a specific column in DataGrid in C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Since the DataGrid column in **C# WPF** does not support `IsTabStop` and I have to set that throughout my app in the code behind it, so based on what I need, did I do the right thing?

```
 public bool PersonNameIsTabStop { get; set; } = false;

 private void MyDataGrid_CurrentCellChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!(MyDataGrid.CurrentColumn is null))
        {
            // Create a new Style for the cell
            Style newCellStyle = new Style(typeof(DataGridCell));
            newCellStyle.BasedOn = PERSON_NAME_COL.CellStyle; // Base it on the existing style
            // Add a Setter to modify the IsTabStop property
            newCellStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(Control.IsTabStopProperty, PersonNameIsTabStop ));
            // Apply the new cell style to the column
            PERSON_NAME_COL.CellStyle = newCellStyle;
        }
    }
```

remember I want to set this in code-behind and dynamically in C#

*Update* :

also I did this :

```
  private void MyDataGrid_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (MyDataGrid.CurrentColumn is not null)
        {
            var DGCI = new DataGridCellInfo(MyDataGrid.Items[CURRENT_ROW_INDEX], MyDataGrid.Columns[MyDataGrid.Columns.FirstOrDefault(c => c.SortMemberPath == "PERSON_NAME").DisplayIndex]);
            var THECELL = Utiliy.GetDataGridCell(DGCI);
            if (!(THECELL is null))
                THECELL.IsTabStop = PersonNameIsTabStop;

        }
    }
```

this one won't work for `CollectionView.NewItemPlaceholder` I mean new row